# ng-route not working. I dont know what's the error because nothing is showing in the console

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

So here's my **boot.php** where I have set the links

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#/valley">Valley</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#/beach">beach</a></li>
</ul>
<ng-view>
</ng-view>
```

Now my angular module file is in js/angular-app.js

```
var loc = angular.module('loc', ['ngRoute']);
```

Now in js/router.js

```
loc.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
              redirectTo: '/valley'
          })
          .when('/valley', {
              templateUrl: 'js/angular/index.php',
              controller: 'js/angular/restaurantController.js'
          })
          .when('/beach', {
              templateUrl: 'js/angular/index.php',
              controller: 'js/angular/restaurantController.js'
          })
});
```

But when click on the links nothing is happening.

Comment: What do you mean nothing is happening? Does it redirect to `/valley`?

Comment: check the net panel from console there may be a continues loop i guess because of this `redirectTo: '/valley'`. If it happens change it as `redirectTo: '/#/valley'`

Comment: no it is not redirecting to valley

Comment: why are not using `.otherwise` to redirect `'/valley'` instread of `.when`

Answer (score 0):

Check your templateUrl and controller path if they are correct. You can try both absolute and relative path.